# How to increment variable 'var' in bash if 'var=08'

Tags: bash, variables, increment

When I increment a variable following error displayed only if the value of variable is **08 or 09**

`a=08;  ((a++));  echo "$a"`

Output

```
~$ a=08;  ((a++));  echo "$a"
bash: ((: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
08
```

What's wrong ??
I want result 09 (not 9. I know 9 can be achieved by `bc <<< "08+01"` )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you prefix a number with a zero, the shell thinks it's an *octal* number, and octal digits go only from 0 to 7.

You might want to keep the number without the leading zero, so it's a normal decimal number, and only add the leading zero when printing the value instead.

```
a=8; ((a++)); printf "%02d\n" $a
```

Comment: Adding @pixelbeat code it's works fine. `a=08; a="`echo $(expr "$a" + 1)`"; printf "%02d\n" $a`

Answer (score 1):

Numbers with leading 0 are interpreted as octal

You could use a separate expr process: `echo $(expr "$a" + 1)`

Or you could use bash specific construct an force base 10 directly: `echo $((10#$a+1))`

Or you could use `expr` to format the var to decimal *once*: `a=$(expr "$a" + 0)`

Comment: Thanks for `echo $(expr "$a" + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

When you put a zero behind a number, it is considered in octal base, where don't exists 09 elements.

Remove 0 of number declaration, if you are working with decimal numbering.

Check google for octal numbers and bash for more clarification.